# Can the dl to appear in two column?

Tags: html

I know how to use `dl dt dl`, but they just list in one column? Can it be in two columns?

Or must I pursue the table instead of `dl`? Any Thoughts?

Sorry, i need to say a little more.
I mean can i just use one dl, one dt in left one right.
so for example the code `<dl><dt>1</dt><dt>2</dt><dt>3</dt><dt>4</dt><dt>5</dt><dt>6</dt></dl>`

is there any way can make it be like 
1 2
3 4
5 6

Comment: What do you want it to look like? And this might have been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325233/dt-with-multiple-dd-on-the-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `dd`'s in column structure, just assign a float left to them as follows:

```
dl {
    width: 80%;
}
dt {
    width: 8em;
}
dd {
    float:left;           
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mQJq7/3/)

Comment: you mean use two dt or just one?  use two and float:left perfect works, but i just try to find solution in one dl. i  refine my question.

Comment: Correct jsfiddle url - http://jsfiddle.net/mQJq7/ - Oh, stackoverflow, how I hate your 6 character minimum edit policy

Answer (score 0):

If you wants the list will be look like Data list then you have to use dl,dt tags only. Or you display it in the different style or you want display your data as 2 columns then you better follow the  **David Thomas**  specified url.Then also you are not satisfied then you can display that data by creating images of the same by using some tools like Photo shop or other...