# How to align dt and dd side-by-side using flexbox with multiple dd underneath the other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a list consisting of key-value-pairs where the key is on the left and the values are on the right side one underneath the other.

```
Authors          John Doe
                 Jane Doe
                 Max Mustermann

Publishers       Johne Doe
                 Jane Doe
                 Max Mustermann
```

My problem is how do I force a line break between each `dd` element? I know this would be easy with floating elements, but I was wondering if it's possible to achieve using flexbox only. Unfortunately, by definition, I cannot wrap the `dd` elements in their own container.

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
}

dt {
  width: 33%;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Authors</dt>
  <dd>John Doe</dd>
  <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
  <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt>Publishers</dt>
  <dd>John Doe</dd>
  <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
  <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Just for the record, I understand that I could simply use one `dd` with multiple `span`s inside or simply use `<br>`.

Comment: We must start with good HTML structure (**not adapt HTML to the simplest CSS**)... And ideal HTML structure say also some *semantic* about the content. So, with this considerations,  this HTML fragment  **is "wrong"**, the typical list use only one `<dl>` for many pairs of title-descriotion itens. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177309/287948

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about setting `flex-wrap` on the `dl` and have a width > 50% for `dd` 
along with `margin-left: auto`?

See demo below:

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
dt {
  width: 33%;
}
dd {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Authors</dt>
  <dd>John Doe</dd>
  <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
  <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
  <dt>Publishers</dt>
  <dd>John Doe</dd>
  <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
  <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: My God, this seems much easier than the overly complicated solution I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/rqyyvr3x/

Answer (score 33):

It's been a few years since this was posted but there is definitely a better way to handle this today using `display: grid`:

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% auto;
}

dt {
  grid-column: 1;
}

dd {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Authors</dt>
    <dd>John Doe</dd>
    <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
    <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>

  <dt>Publishers</dt>
    <dd>John Doe</dd>
    <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
    <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Especially if you don't want to use percentages.

Comment: Further simplification `You can eliminate the column settings and use max-content. `dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}`

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: the question have **not a good snippet code of HTML** (the bellow is better).
... We must start with good HTML structure (**not adapt HTML to the simplest CSS**). And ideal HTML structure say also some *semantic* about the content.

---

### One `dl` list with all items!

The typical applications of `<dl>`/(`<dt>`+`<dd>`) lists are like `<ul>`/`<li>` lists, but using key-value pairs instead bullets.

```html
Only one description list:
<dl>
  <dt>Authors</dt>
    <dd>John Doe</dd>
    <dd>Jane Doe</dd>
    <dd>Max Mustermann</dd>

  <dt>Etc</dt>
    <dd>etc...</dd>

  <dt>Publishers</dt>
    <dd>John Willey</dd>
    <dd>Miramax</dd>
    <dd>Mary Max</dd>
</dl>

Other list, now starting with one descriptor-item:
<dl>
  <dt>Test</dt> <dd>One desscriptor here</dd>
  <dt>Etc</dt> <dd>etc...</dd>
</dl>
```

In this context the solution commented by @kukkuz is valid, with some adaptations for the case where we have only one `dd` per `dt`, as [this other JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2hLyaa3/).

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;  
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 1em;  
}
dd {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

dd + dd {
  width: 100%; 
  padding-top: 0;  
}
dt + dd:not(:nth-child(2)),
dt:first-child + dd:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
}
dd + dd::before {
  width: 25%;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 0
}
```

To really typical and generic (flex) applications, we need to avoid problems with little screens (smarthphones), so put all into a `@media` block,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
   ... all above CSS here ...
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  dt {
    font-weight: bold;  
    width: 33%;
    padding-top: 1em;  
  }
}
```

See [jsfiddle.net/m5qh8g7r](https://jsfiddle.net/m5qh8g7r/).