# How to say to Android's Chorme that my page need @media conditional directive?

Tags: css, mobile

I am using [this "pure HTML + CSS" solution to a flex-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177309/287948), that is working fine when I change window size at my desktop browser, but when view the same page in a mobile device, specifically Android's Chrome, the browser do a "zoom out" instead to use CSS `@media screen and (max-width: 360px)` directive.

How to say to  Chrome to use the directive and not doo zoom-out? I need to use a kind of *viewport*? And the viewport not destroys the desktop layout?

Comment: do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your document `<head>`?

Comment: Hum..  That is a good clue (!) Thanks @TrobFrank I will test tomorow this  viewport (scale=1 make sense!).

Comment: Tested: YES, it is the solution!  Please @TrobFrank, post your comment as  answer, and you will take the 50 votes of  bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your document `<head>`.

Please see the tutorials or spec for more information for why this is necessary:

- ["Viewport basics" at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics)
- [CSS Responsive Web Design (RWD) /  Viewport at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)
- https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html
- [**W3C official draft specification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/). 
  In nowadays the "live reference" is yet the [Apple's specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).

PS: [question/answer about javascript access to Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939697/287948)