# Using flexbox align firsl li of ul to the left and the rest to the right and make them columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a ul with n li's, the first one should behave like a title, and the rest like options, the thing is that the first one is at the left and the rest at the right and on top of each other.

```
<ul>
    <li>TITLE</li>
    <li>option</li>
    <li>option</li>
    <li>option</li>
    <li>option</li>
</ul>
```

I can't alter the html structure (wraping in divs, etc.)

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Title                  option
                       option 
                       option 
                       option
```

Is there a way to do this? with flexbox or plain css? thanks in advance

**Edit:** I can't use definition lists because the functionality is made using ul and li, if I change the HTML structure the functionality won't work, and if I change the functionality other similar structures will stop working.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762697/how-to-align-dt-and-dd-side-by-side-using-flexbox-with-multiple-dd-underneath-th/40762801#40762801)

Comment: ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {flex-basis: 50%}
li:nth-child(n+3) {flex-basis: 50.01%; margin-left: auto}

Comment: you don't need to change the structure, keep it the same and apply the same code as the duplicate

Comment: @epresas first you can target all `li` by using selector `ul li` and just below that target the `li:first-child` of `ul`... try it out...

Comment: @epresas use these styles - `ul li {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 66%;
}
ul li:first-child {
  width: 33%;
}` in that order...